# Wordpress files Question

Tags: php, javascript, image, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i don't know how to ask my doubt... i will try to make my question easy...

i created a new html file and tried to convert it into wordpress theme.. when i tried to include the files (image,js or anything) using "/sub-directory/filename" it is not including... when i change it into "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/ashok/sub-directory/filename", it is working fine...

i don't know what is the problem... can u please help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/image.png
```

Works with every type of file.
If you need to include a template part, let's say **search-form.php** use:

```
<?php get_template_part('search-form'); // So, without .php extension ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
"<?php echo get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/sub-directory/filename"
```

Answer (score 0):

To use this function with subfolders in your theme directory, simply prepend the folder name before the slug. For example, if you have a folder called “partials” in your theme directory and a template part called “content-page.php” in that sub-folder, you would use get_template_part() like this:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

`<?php get_template_part( 'partials/content', 'page' ); ?>`